# How to assign default value in deltalake

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have following ddl for customer table

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer (
  name string NOT NULL
  ,id string NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No ID'
  ,age INT
) using delta
```

While creating table in deltalake getting issue  with `default` keyword

Can anyone help me , how to define default value in ddl for deltalake ?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Create delta table does not support DEFAULT keyword :

> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] table_identifier   [ ( col_name1 col_type1 [ NOT
> NULL ] [ GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( generation_expression1 ) ] [ COMMENT
> col_comment1 ], ... ) ]   USING DELTA   [ LOCATION
>  ]

This is called [`generated-column`](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#use-generated-columns):

```sql
id STRING GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST('No ID' AS STRING)),
```

Comment: If user defines any other value after creation of table will be it stored ?

Comment: @SMValiAli of course, the SQL expression `CAST('No ID' AS STRING)` is only used to generate the values if they are not explicitly provided when writing to table.

Comment: spark.sql("""create table demo_deltalake.customer(
  name string not null,
  id string GENERATED ALWAYS  as (cast('No ID' as string)),
  age int
)using delta""") 

I used this command in databricks

but getting below error 

ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'create table demo_deltalake.customer(\n  name string not null,\n  id string GENERATED'(line 3, pos 12)

== SQL ==
create table demo_deltalake.customer(
  name string not null,
  id string GENERATED ALWAYS  as (cast('No ID' as string)),
------------^^^
  age int
)using delta

Comment: after using GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce('No ID', name)) getting same issue as no viable alternative at input

Comment: @SMValiAli can you try with`GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substring(name, 0, 1))`? just to confirm it works in your environment

Comment: GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substring(name, 0, 1))  is also not working

Comment: @SMValiAli hmm strange... what version are you using? in the doc it says `This feature is available on Databricks Runtime 8.3 and above.`

Comment: Okay I am using 7.0  . Sorry you have asked many times  .

Comment: So is there any other alternative @blackbishop ?